# Remove Certain Words From MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables, `users` and `email_logs`, `users` have columns `name` and `email` and table `email_logs` has column `email`. What I want to do is to fetch all emails and names from `users` table, and if certain email is already present in `email_logs` table then it shouldn't be fetched.

I tried this:

```
    $emails_array = 'one@gmail.com, two@gmail.com, three@gmail.com';
    $query = $db->query("SELECT name,email FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE email NOT IN ({$emails_array})");
```

But it didn't removed those already present emails in `email_logs` table.

Please help!

Comment: The emails would have to be enclosed in quotes if you're using `NOT IN`. Try `$emails_array = "'one@gmail.com', 'two@gmail.com', 'three@gmail.com'";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name,email
FROM users WHERE email NOT IN (SELECT email FROM email_logs);
```

Comment: That's an amazing answer! Thanks Tin Tran :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name,u.email FROM users u
LEFT JOIN email_logs as e ON u.email = e.email
WHERE e.email is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails_array = "'apple', 'banana', 'coconut'";

SELECT u.name, u.email FROM users u
WHERE u.email NOT IN ( {$emails_array} )
```

Your `IN` was used incorrectly.
Each string/email should be enclosed in quotes, like:

`WHERE u.email NOT IN ( 'apple', 'banana', 'coconut' )`

Answer (score 0):

The reason as to why this doesn't work is because rather than creating an array, you created one huge string against which the query checks.

Rather, try using this:

```
$emails_array = array( 'one@gmail.com', 'two@gmail.com', 'three@gmail.com' );
```

For defining a string with three emails:

```
$email_string = "'" . implode( "', '", $emails_array ) . "'";
```

Finally, run your query

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT name,email FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."users WHERE email NOT IN ({$email_string})");
```